# alt+shift can't be set to toggle language

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, 13.10, language-support

I recently did a fresh installation of Ubuntu 13.10; but there is something bothering me, which I don't quite understand.

When I first tried to toggle the keyboard language(I usually switch between Persian and English) using the good old "<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>" shortcut it didn't work. Then, I went and checked the Keyboard shortcut settings and found out that it had been set to "<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>"(which BTW didn't work either). So I tried to change it back to "<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>" but it just doesn't work; when I press "<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>" to set it up as the toggle-language shortcut, the box automatically resets itself to its previous value(without any errors whatsoever). As far as I've checked I couldn't find any thing obvious corresponding to the shortcut "<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>" either.

I've currently set up the shortcut as "<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>"; so I can toggle the language. My question is why I cannot set it up to just "<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>"?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Which is a duplicate itself as well!!

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem after upgrading to Saucy.

Here's how  I fixed it.
First you need dconf-editor, so just install it by typing (in a terminal):

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
```

After installed run it by typing

```
dconf-editor
```

In the new window browse to `Desktop -> ibus -> General -> Hotkey`
then change the `next-engine` & `next-engine-in-menu` values to something like this:

```
['Shift_L+Alt']
```

Close the window and go to the text entry settings.
They should now allow you to use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>

#### if the above doesn't help, try this :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:attente/1218322
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

then restart.

Comment: Hi Taleb, I just tried what you said, but it didn't work for me.

Comment: try the second fix that i just added

Comment: Second method worked!

Comment: `GOOD POINT:` The first method didn't work when I pasted ['Shift_L+Alt'] then I left it as is and went to `Text Entry Settings` here I changed the keyboard shortcut to ALT+SHIFT for both. At first it gave me an error message but for the second time it worked. I didn't add attente.

Comment: I love you <3 .. first method worked like a charm!

Comment: this did not work for me.  The repository doesn't exist anymore as of 6 January 2020.

Answer (score 1):

To set Shift+Alt combination as your language switcher use the following:

```
Tweak Tool -> Typing -> Key(s) to change layout
```

This will change the layout using whatsoever key combination you chose from the menu. But it will **not** change the Layout indicator in Ubuntu 13.10 (Unity)

Install [Tweak Tool](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gnome-tweak-tool/) from Ubuntu Software Center

Comment: It didn't work for me.

Comment: Try typing while you are switching layouts, do not look at the layout indicator, it will not affect the indicator.

Comment: It doesn't work for me either. Tweak Tool shows my choice (CapsLock), but switching doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem

After I installed

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:attente/1218322

That didn't work. So I openned

> dconf-editor 
>   Desktop -> ibus -> General -> Hotkey

There combination 'Shift_L+Alt' was already set for next-engine & next-engine-in-menu, but has nothing changed. So I changed

>
[Shift_L+Alt'] 
to 
[]
>

After reboot I was able to set 'Shift+Alt' key in 'Text Entry Settings'