# Mate IBus not accepting changes to "next input method"

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, mate, ibus

I'm on Ubuntu Mate, and when I change the "Next Input method" to "Alt Shift" so that I can switch input methods like I do on Windows.

However, even after restarting, typing "Alt shift" does not change the input method.

How can I get Mate's input method to change when typing "Alt shift"?
[image: iBus Preferences]

Comment: same problem here

Comment: Same issue, responses don't work in 2023: https://askubuntu.com/questions/361516/altshift-cant-be-set-to-toggle-language